# WebSocket with SSL

Tags: ssl, websocket

Is it possible to have WebSockets with HTTPS?

When switching to HTTPS, my WebSocket returns a security error and works perfectly with regular HTTP.

Below, a snippet;

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://my_www:1235");
```

Comment: my bad, i realized that the AIR socket server i'm using isn't secure, i have to rewrite to use flash.net.SecureSocket...

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The WebSocket connection starts its life with an HTTP or HTTPS handshake. When the page is accessed through HTTP, you can use WS or WSS (WebSocket secure: WS over TLS) . However, when your page is loaded through HTTPS, you can only use WSS - browsers don't allow to "downgrade" security.

Comment: that's what i have but i realized that the AIR socket server i'm using isn't secure, i have to rewrite to use flash.net.SecureSocket...

Comment: Flash has its serious problems as well... Are you building a WebSocket server (if so, why), or are you building an app?

Comment: I have a AIR socket server running yes.

Comment: So how to select WSS if page is not loaded with HTTP?

Answer (score 55):

You can't use WebSockets over HTTPS, but you can use WebSockets over TLS (HTTPS is HTTP over TLS). Just use "wss://" in the URI.

I believe recent version of Firefox won't let you use non-TLS WebSockets from an HTTPS page, but the reverse shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So, what's the solution? I've a WS server running over http now I bought an SSL and browser no more allow me to connect with WS. I turned WS to WSS:// and now its not connecting with WebSocket

Comment: @muaaz your WebSocket server should be running in WSS mode and preferably loaded with the same SSL cert/keys as your webserver that is serving your origin web pages which are trying to connect to the websocket server.

Comment: Thank you. btw, I've just solved it by Proxying(using apache) the request from `wss://` to `ws://`. So, I use `wss://ws.domain.com` and apache apply the proxy on it and redirect request where the WS server is running. e.g: `ws://10.12.23.45:5641/server.php`. and I know its a very bad solution - although, it works for me. I'd appreciate your help if you guide me through the apache configuration. e.g: where to put the `.cert` etc. thanks!

Comment: @muaaz sorry, I don't know the apache configuration apart from googling it myself.

Answer (score 27):

1 additional caveat (besides the answer by kanaka/peter): if you use WSS, and the server certificate is not acceptable to the browser, you may not get *any browser rendered dialog* (like it happens for Web pages). This is because WebSockets is treated as a so-called "subresource", and certificate accept / security exception / whatever dialogs are not rendered for subresources.

Comment: Even if it is the same certifcate as the one used for HTTPS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "browser rendered dialog"? Like `alert()`?

Comment: Dialogs that natively originate within the browser (not a page). Like "this cert is invalid, do you want to continue?"

Comment: so is there a way to overcome this? if i use self-signed certificate, can i still use websocket?

Answer (score 3):

To support the answer by @oberstet, if the cert is not trusted by the browser (for example you get a "this site is not secure, do you want to continue?") one solution is to open the browser options, navigate to the certificates settings and add the host and post that the websocket server is being served from to the certificate provider as an exception.

for example add 'example-wss-domain.org:6001' as an exception to 'Certificate Provider Ltd'.

In firefox, this can be done from 'about:preferences' and searching for 'Certificates'