# How can I run the secure websocket server in Android / iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, websocket

I am developing an cordova application for Android & iOS. In both platforms I am running the web socket servers with the help of libraries ([Android](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), [iOS](https://github.com/mirek/CoreWebSocket)) and loading my site into the cordova app with the url. In javascript am connecting to the native websocket server with `ws://localhost<port>`. So for working fine. But when I move my site to production server which is loaded as `https`. So  websocket communication failed because of `ws` tried by giving `wss` but no use. :( Please help me to fix this issue.

How can I run the websocket server with `wss` in localhost.

Thanks.

Comment: You might learn something from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for ur comment, But I know that one, So is there any way to run the websocket server with secure in iOS & Android apps. So I can connect to them with `wss://localhost<port>`

Comment: I don't think there is a library for mobile that has a websocket server with SSL support. But why don't you try running the server somewhere else and connect the phone(s) to it. You can send the same dat as when the phone was the server.

Comment: Am using this library for Android [TooTallNate](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket#wss-support), they said it supports wss, there is a link in that if we need to work with android devices. And for your second question, earlier we used android device as client, For some requirement we moved to server.