# Websockets. Downgrade gracefully from WSS to WS

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, websocket

I am trying to write a websocket client for a project I'm working on. However I want to make the code generic enough to be abe to downgrade gracefully to non secure sockets (with a warning, of course), but I haven't been able to find how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt you can downgrade from SSL (`wss`) to non-SSL (`ws`). An SSL loaded page (using `https`)  should (and probably will) refuse any non-SSL javascript websocket or AJAX... When websocket developers talk about "downgrading gracefully", we usually refer to using AJAX when Websockets aren't available.

Comment: @Myst Yeah, I was thinking along those lines also, but who knows, maybe I'm wrong. I believe you can ws on an https page, I did some tests some time ago and I think that was one of them.

Comment: I believe not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl