# Mixed Content error when accessing WebSocket server hosted in a different port

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, websocket, certificate

I've set up an `express` server with `node.js` on port 80 (http) and 443 (https). Separate from that server, I've set up a websocket server in a separate port, `8000`:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8000});
```

The site served by express must connect to those services to work. The issue is: accessing my site through `http` works fine, but, from `https`, I get:

```
index.js:100 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was 
loaded over HTTPS,  but attempted to connect to the insecure 
WebSocket endpoint 'ws://my_sites_ip:8000/'. This request has been 
blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

Why I'm getting this error? Has this anything to do with the fact the websocket server is in a different process/port than the http server? How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 33):

The error is telling you what to do. Use websocket with wss when using https

Look at this post 
[html5 Websocket with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl)
The WebSocket connection starts its life with an HTTP or HTTPS handshake. When the page is accessed through HTTP, you can use WS or WSS (WebSocket secure: WS over TLS) . However, when your page is loaded through HTTPS, you can only use WSS - browsers don't allow to "downgrade" security.

Comment: Hi Where I have to use WSS?

Comment: You have to switch the URL scheme and the port.

For example:
wss://test.mosquitto.org:8081

Instead of:
ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080

Comment: This would be pretty insightful for the guys trying to run Vue Vite HMR module from inside a docker container.