# Why is this websocket connection being refused?

Tags: go, proxy, websocket, slack

I try to use the slack-sample bot from this blogpost https://www.opsdash.com/blog/slack-bot-in-golang.html . I've successfully created my api token, but i can not connect to the websocket server (the rtm.start request passs normally). I've get the error message

> ```
> dial tcp 54.242.95.213:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
> ```

I've also tried to connect via a chrome app called **Simple Web Socket Client** and via a website based one tester. Both work well, i can establish a connection and i can send data.

I'm behind a proxy, but i only have troubles with golang's websocket.Dial function.

Does anybody know why this can happen?

I use:
- Windows 7 SP1 x64
- Golang 1.7.1 windows/amd64

Greetings
Tonka

Comment: Can you connect to ws with http? The url in that example uses http

Comment: Turns out you [can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl). Are you reading the response from the http call ? Looks like [that](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start) provides you with the wss url to connect to

Comment: Where is the http call?

Comment: the blog example already give me a wss address!

Comment: Can you post your exact code? I cannot connect to that IP address.

Comment: The link in my post contains the code, i have exactly this code. It seems that our proxy is the problem, without it it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [gorilla/websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/), it has the ability to use a Proxy. From [issue 107](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/107):

```
import "net/http"

...

var dialer = websocket.Dialer{
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
}
```

If you are using [golang.org/x/net](http://golang.org/x/net) you should switch to gorilla/websocket.

Comment: Thx, i will try gorilla's websocket lib