# WebSocket via ws not connecting but wss is

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I am creating a websocket server using vtortola's websocketserver nugget. 
When I attempt to connect to the server through the external ip using hercules it connects (but obviously fails negotiation), and when I also attempt to connect to it through javascript on a different computer on the same network it connects fine as well, but when I use one of the online websocket echo testers (ie. https://www.websocket.org/echo.html), it fails to connect at all. When analyzing the port on wireshark, the request never even comes through. Strangly enough, when I change the schema to wss, i can then see the request coming in, although it obviously fails again. The appropriate ports are forwarded on my router, and dmz is enabled. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page you are connecting from is HTTPS, you cannot connect to a ws:// websocket. The browser does not allow you to downgrade security.

You may be interested in a similar question: [html5 Websocket with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl)

Comment: ah ok i see, i believe this is the reason:: 

"... recent version of Firefox won't let you use non-TLS WebSockets from an HTTPS page, but the reverse shouldn't be a problem."