# Ambassador Gives 403 Trying to Connect to Websocket

Tags: kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, ambassador

Ambassador is throwing a 403 while trying to access a websocket endpoint within the cluster. Here are the steps to recreate the issue:

[Kube Environment: Docker for Desktop on Mac]

**Install Ambassador and the Echo Service**

1. Deploy Ambassador with Helm

```sh
helm repo add datawire https://getambassador.io
helm install ambassador datawire/ambassador
```

2. Deploy the websocket echo deployment/service/mapping

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websocket-echo
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: websocket-echo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: websocket-echo
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: websocket-echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: websocket-echo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: jmalloc/echo-server
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: websocket-echo
  namespace: default
spec:
  prefix: /websocket/
  service: websocket-echo
  allow_upgrade:
  - websocket
```

**✅ Verify the echo server can be reached from a pod within the cluster**

1. Create a node shell on the cluster

```sh
kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image node:12 -- bash
```

2. In the shell, download `wscat`

```sh
npm i -g wscat
```

3. In the shell, connect to the service via the cluster service endpoint

```sh
wscat -c websocket-echo.default.svc.cluster.local
```

4. Verify the connection is established and messages can be echoed back

**❌ Verify the echo server cannot be reach from outside the cluster**

1. Install `wscat` on you local machine

```
npm i -g wscat
```

2. Using wscat, connect to the service using the mapping

```sh
wscat -c localhost/websocket-echo/
```

3. Verify that the error returned is `error: Unexpected server response: 403`

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Port 80 is for you to use in the cluster , either use kubectl portforward or try Nodeport service type and then access with localhost:Nodeport

Comment: He's using `Docker for Desktop on Mac`. Therefore, it's ok to do `localhost[:80]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambassador will redirect incoming request froms http to https.

You can verify by

```sh
$ curl localhost/websocket/ -v
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /websocket/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< location: https://localhost/websocket/
< date: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 08:25:38 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

So, you will need to add this config to disable redirection on `localhost`

```yaml
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Host
metadata:
  name: localhost
  namespace: default
spec:
  hostname: localhost
  acmeProvider:
    authority: none
  requestPolicy:
    insecure:
      action: Route
```

### Reference

- https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/running/tls/cleartext-redirection/#cleartext-routing
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752145/3854890