# Blazor WebAssembly MQTT over websockets not working

Tags: ssl, websocket, mqtt, blazor-webassembly, paho

I'm trying to implement an mqtt over websocket client subscriber in Blazor using Paho. The problem is it insists on using wss instead of ws and throws an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error upon connection.

Here's a simplified code block:

```
var mqtt;
var host = "api.mydomainexample.com";
var port = 1884;
function onConnect(){
   console.log("connected ! Now listening for messages ..");
   mqtt.subscribe("someTopic");
}

function onFailure(message){
   console.log("connection to host failed: " + message);
}

function onMessageArrived(msg){
   var message = "Message received on topic '"+ msg.destinationName +"': "+ msg.payloadString;
   console.log(message);
}

function mqttConnect() {
   console.log("connecting to " + host + " ..");
   mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, clientid);
   var options = {
       timeout: 3,
       onSuccess: onConnect,
       onFailure: onFailure,
       useSSL: false
   };
   mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
   mqtt.connect(options);
}
```

I copied this code into an html page created in notepad, called the function from the html body and ran the file in browser. It worked and subscribed well.
Also I added `useSSL: false` in the connection options although I didnt have it before but still didnt work.

here's the error I'm having from console:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.mydomainexample:1884/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I also changed my projects launch settings so that it launches as http and not https because based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752145/1554660), I cannot use a ws from a page loaded through https.

Any ideas ? Can't I just connect to a websocket without certificate in blazor?

Comment: If you load the page over https then you MUST use wss for Websockets. The browser will not let you use lower security protocols if you load the page securely

Comment: exactly, that's why I loaded it in http but it's still using wss.

Comment: Are you loading the paho lib from a CDN?

Comment: yes I'm embedding the link in index.htm: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out that when creating the blazor application, there is an option to `'configure on https'` where this option causes requests redirection from `http` to `https` and consequently asks for secure wss instead of ws.

Hope this helps someone!